# How can I call a function?

Tags: symfony4, phpspreadsheet

I have a function in a class in App/src/utils. I have issue using it from a controller.

I have to construct some sheets with phpspreadsheet. The method length is 260 lines. 
I don't think it's a good practice to have it in a function of the controller. 
So, I try to put it in a class (ExcelCreate) I have created in App/Utils, in a public function called excelfrais, which create the sheet, using an array, called $data, and 2 variables called $user and $nblig. The function save the sheet, and send it to the browser. 
I put a "use App\Utils\ExcelCreate;" in my controller
I call the function from the controller.

```
    use App\Utils\ExcelCreate;
    ...
class ComiteController extends Controller
    {
    public function frais(Request $request, $nblig)
        { ...
                $data=$form->getData();
                $nblig=$data['nblig'];
                excelfrais($user,$data,$nblig); ...
        }}
```

And there is my issue : I have an Exception : Attempted to call function "excelfrais" from namespace "App\Controller"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a big search. Reading carefully the Symfony documentation I found there : https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html the solution : 
in the function of my controller, I need to have a use of the class whose the function is a property :

```
public function frais(Request $request, ExcelCreate $create, $nblig)
    {...}
```

and the call to this function should be

```
$create->excelfrais($user,$data,$nblig);
```